# Why Swift Mailer let to send message without password?

Tags: php, swiftmailer, hmail-server

Using SwiftMailer package in php and local mail server hMailServer. Php code:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$message=Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setFrom('webmaster@mail.com');
$message->setTo(array('testmail@mail.com'=>'Ilqar Rasulov'));
$message->setSubject('Delicious New Recipe');
//$message->setBody(<<<_TEXT_
//Dear James,
//You should try this: puree 1 pound of chicken with two pounds
//of asparagus in the blender, then drop small balls of the mixture
//into a deep fryer. Yummy!
//Love,
//Julia
//_TEXT_
//);
$message->addPart(<<<_TEXT_
<p>Dear James,</p>
<p>You should try this:</p>
<ul>
<li>puree 1 pound of chicken with two pounds
of asparagus in the blender</li>
<li>then drop small balls of the mixture into a deep fryer.</li>
</ul>    
<p><em>Yummy!</em></p>
<p>Love,</p>
<p>Julia</p>
_TEXT_
, "text/html");
try{
$transport= Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('localhost',25);
$mailer=  Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

$mailer->send($message);
}  catch (Exception $ex){
    print $ex->getMessage();
}
```

I have configured my hMailServer and assigned passwords (admin and accounts password). So question is why swiftmailer needs only hostname and password to do its job, and doen't require authentification? Cuz I cann't remember that I stored username and password in any configuration files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to send your email from hMailServer, you need to create a transport object like this (as explained [here](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#smtp-with-a-username-and-password)):

```
// Create the Transport the call setUsername() and setPassword()
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.example.org', 25)
  ->setUsername('username')
  ->setPassword('password')
  ;

// Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
```

Also note that you need to replace `smtp.example.org`, `username`and `passwort` with your corresponding settings of hMailServer.

Currently your script does not send the email via hMailServer but from the server where your script is located with the [php mail() function](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php). You can use any `FROM` address with the `mail()` function, but many email provider will recognize this as spam. So its a good idea to create a transport object.

Comment: so it looks like till this point i sent mail without entering mail server? I changed to any unexisting address in "from" and it worked! After changing to your variant it started checking username and password. Thanks for answer, now I got idea of how it works